# Picking random points using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to geocode some OSM roads and I have created a table with a sample of 500 roads. All of the roads are multilinestrings. I have created another table using ST_DumpPoints so now I have one more table with the roads info where each entry is a single point from a single road. The 500 records from the initial sample table have turned to 48000. I would like to create a third table in which there would be three random points from a single road.

The points table:

```
| gid   | number | path   | path1 | path2 | geom | text_geom  |
|-------|--------|--------|-------|-------|------|------------|
| 39559 | 49     | {1,1}  | 1     | 1     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 39559 | 49     | {1,2}  | 1     | 2     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 39559 | ...    | ...    | ...   | ...   | ...  | ...        |
| 39559 | 49     | {1,79} | 1     | 79    | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 15168 | Null   | {1,1}  | 1     | 1     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 15168 | Null   | {1,2}  | 1     | 2     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 15168 | ...    | ...    | ...   | ...   | ...  | ...        |
| 15168 | Null   | {1,43} | 1     | 43    | ...  | POINT(x y) |
```

Note: some entries have 1800 points to pick from. This table is just to show what it looks like.

The table I would like to have:

```
| gid   | number | path  | path1 | path2 | geom | text_geom  |
|-------|--------|-------|-------|-------|------|------------|
| 39559 | 49     | {1,1} | 1     | 1     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 39559 | 49     | {1,2} | 1     | 2     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 39559 | 49     | {1,3} | 1     | 3     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 15168 | Null   | {1,1} | 1     | 1     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 15168 | Null   | {1,2} | 1     | 2     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 14005 | 460    | {1,1} | 1     | 1     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 14005 | 460    | {1,2} | 1     | 2     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
| 14005 | 460    | {1,3} | 1     | 3     | ...  | POINT(x y) |
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that all of the entries have more than three points to pick from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cdd093ffbbf441461d386c8573b593e0)

You can use the [row_number() window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which generates consecutive numbers for each record within a group with a specific order. The group is your `gid`, I guess, and as order you could simply take the `random()` value.

I demonstrated this with a more simplyfied table: `myroad` is your `gid` and `mypoint` is your `text_geom` columnb:

```
SELECT
    myroad,
    mypoint
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY myroad ORDER BY random())
    FROM
        points
) s
WHERE row_number <= 3
```